# Виснет FTP-подключение

Tags: c#, tcp-ip, .net

Доброе время суток.

Мучался весь день сегодня, такое у меня первый раз, короче, в общих чертах, сделал класс для просмотра каталога FTP в удобном формате. Я отправляю серверу запрос на пассивный режим, в ответ он должен мне вернуть IP и порт для прослушки, но вместо этого в сообщении он возвращает предыдущий ответ, допустим, если до команды PASV было PASS, то вернет, мол пользователь зареган и то, что положена команде PASS, a не PASV. Причем когда я делаю дебаг, я дважды запрашиваю пассивный режим, то все работает, но когда пускаю через ctrl+f5 то через пару секунд вылетает исключение, что сервер не ответил и все такое. (Язык C#, для подключения юзаю TcpClient.)

Не знаю, насколько внятно смог объяснить проблему, если что могу еще добавлять, просто уже очень я замучался уже, и хочу все-таки понять, в чем же дело, кто поможет - огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поднимите у себя сервер - сможете отследить, чем отличаются сессии.

Или поставьте туже файлзиллу - она показывает командную сессию с сервером красиво.

Комманды PASS, кстати нету - это операнд ввода пароля и только после USER. 
Есть PASV - переключение в пассивный режим.

Протокол:

```
<220 привет от сервера
>USER login
<331 Введите пароль
>PASS 123123123
<Если тут 2ХХ - то можно дальше. Если 5ХХ - то идите нафиг, пароль не тот.
```

И только тут можно делать переключение в *PASV*-режим.

Кстати перед этим рекомендуют выполнить *FEAT* - и получить список команд.

Comment: спасибо будем пробовать)